# Problems packaging on buster

Tags: makefile, debian-buster, autogen, dpkg-buildpackage, fakeroot

I'm trying to build some packages from source, and I'm facing trouble that I don't understand despite lots of googling. This happens with some packages, while others compile and get packed normally. One of the softwares that fail to package is libva.

When I use;

```
export DH_VERBOSE=1 && dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -j4 -d --build=full --host-arch=amd64 --target-arch=amd64
```

I get this error;

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `./autogen.sh': machine `./autogen.sh' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ./autogen.sh failed
    find ! -ipath "./debian/*" -a ! \( -path '*/.git/*' -o -path '*/.hg/*' -o -path '*/.bzr/*' -o -path '*/.svn/*' -o -path '*/CVS/*' \) -a  -type f -exec md5sum {} + -o -type l -printf "symlink  %p
" > debian/autoreconf.after
dh_autoreconf: ./autogen.sh ./autogen.sh returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:12: override_dh_autoreconf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/libva-2.14.0'
make: *** [debian/rules:9: binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
```

I also have the architecture set up in the control file.

However when I run;

```
autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-drm --enable-x11 --enable-glx --enable-wayland --enable-va-messaging
```

it compiles normally, but I face another problem trying to install it to the same folder under fakeroot.

```
$ fakeroot make install
Making install in va
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/build/va'
Making install in drm
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/build/va/drm'
make[3]: Entering directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/build/va/drm'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/include/va'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../../libva/va/drm/va_drm.h '/usr/include/va'
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove '/usr/include/va/va_drm.h': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [Makefile:502: install-libva_drmincludeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/build/va/drm'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:620: install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/build/va/drm'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:755: install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/deyaa/BBuffer/buildfolder/intel/libva/build/va'
make: *** [Makefile:459: install-recursive] Error 1
```

I get similar errors while building other packages, like aria2, and intel-media.

I compile on debian buster, with stock gcc, glibc, and libtool.

Could you offer any help or pointers?